# Symmetry argument for Pólya's urn scheme

Tags: probability, polya-urn-model

In case of Pólya's urn model, an urn initially contains $r$  red balls and $b$ blue balls. At each stage a ball is randomly selected from the urn and is then returned along with $m$ other balls of the same color. How to prove that at stage $n$ a red ball is selected with probability $\frac{r}{b+r}$ using symmetry argument. (Note that it is same as the probability at stage 1).

Comment: any solution hint on it ?

Comment: I answered this at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/378846 .

Answer (score 2):

You can show this by induction:

**Initial case:** after the first draw, either you have $r+m$ red balls and $b$ blue balls  with probability $\frac{r}{r+b}$,or you have  $r$ red balls and $b+m$ blue balls with probability $\frac{b}{r+b}$, so in the second draw the probability of drawing a red ball is $  \frac{r}{r+b}\frac{r+m}{r+b+m} +  \frac{b}{r+b}\frac{r}{r+b+m} =  \frac{r}{r+b}$.

**Inductive case:** suppose after $k$ draws you have pattern indexed by $K_j$ with $r_{k_j}$ red balls and $b_{k_j}$ blue balls having probability $p_{k_j}$, such that  $r_{k_j}+b_{k_j}=r+b+km$ and $\displaystyle \sum_j p_{k_j} \frac{r_{k_j}}{r_{k_j}+b_{k_j}} = \frac{r}{r+b}$, i.e. the probability of drawing a red ball in the $k+1^\text{th}$ draw is $\frac{r}{r+b}$, so $\sum_j p_{k_j} {r_{k_j}} = (r+b+km)\frac{r}{r+b}$ and since $\sum_j p_{k_j} =1$ you have $\sum_j p_{k_j} m=m$.

Then the probability of drawing a red ball in the $k+2^\text{th}$ draw is $$ \displaystyle  \frac{r}{r+b}\sum_j p_{k_j} \frac{r_{k_j}+m}{r_{k_j}+b_{k_j}+m} +  \frac{b}{r+b}\sum_j p_{k_j} \frac{r_{k_j}}{r_{k_j}+b_{k_j}+m}$$ $$=\frac{r(r+b+km)\frac{r}{r+b} + rm + b(r+b+km)\frac{r}{r+b}}{(r+b)(r+b+km+m)}  $$  $$=\frac{r}{r+b}.$$

So, by induction, this is the probability for all draws.

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer.If I'm correct, the latter formula relies on the fact that $P(K_j|X_{k+1}=b)=p_{K_j}$ which means that $K_j$ and $X_{k+1}=b$ are independent. How can I prove this ? thx

Comment: @mFriction: Your notation is not quite the same as mine but if I understand yours correctly then I do not think that your fact is right: the pattern after $k$ draws and the event of drawing a blue ball on the $k+1$th draw would not be independent (knowing a blue ball was drawn on the $k+1$th draw would increase the probabilities of having had a pattern with more blue balls after $k$ draws compared with the probabilities not knowing the outcome of the $k+1$th draw).

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. Then can you explain from where does the last formula come from ?

Comment: It is the probability of drawing a red ball on the $k+1$th draw multiplied by the conditional probability of drawing a red ball on the $k+2$th ball, plus the probability of drawing a blue ball on the $k+1$th draw multiplied by the conditional probability of drawing a red ball on the $k+2$th ball, so in aggregate the marginal probability of drawing a red ball on the $k+2$th ball.

Comment: It this notion of agregation of marginal probability that is not clear for me how you obtain it. Best