# Basketball scores - solving 2 variable recurrence relation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, recurrence-relations

My question is a follow up to the famous problem 'Basketball Scores' from the green book. The question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426159/66-points-in-100-shots):

> A person shoots basketball 100 times. First time he scores a point and second time he misses it. For the following shots, the probability of him scoring a point is equal to number of points scored before this shot divided by number of shots taken before this shot, for ex: if he is into his 21st shot and he has scored 13 points in the first 20 shots then the probability of him scoring in 21st shot is 13/20. What is the probability of scoring 66 points in the 100 shots (including the first two)

The general solution is for any $1 \le x \le n-1$:

$$P(x, n) = \frac{1}{n - 1}$$

where for the specific problem ($n=100$ and $x=66$) is  $\frac{1}{99}$.

I solved the problem using the factorial approach. I also understand how the following recurrence is formed and the answer is verified using **induction** in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2426185/1231520), in which we need **to know the answer**.

> My question is, **how do I solve for $P(x, n)$ using the following 2-variable recurrence relation without knowing the answer**?

$$P(x,n) = P(x-1,n-1)\left(\frac{x-1}{n-1}\right) + P(x,n-1)\left(\frac{n-1 - x}{n-1}\right)$$

I know that we can use generating functions to solve for single variable recurrences. How exactly do I extend that here and arrive at the result that $P(x, n) = \frac{1}{n - 1}?$ Any other method to solve this recurrence or any intuitive reason explaining why the answer is independent of k (without using factorials) would also be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to solve the recurrence relation without induction?

Comment: Yeah. Basically, in order to "solve" it using induction, I would require to know the answer, right? That's how induction works. My question is how do I get to the answer in the first place? How do I actually SOLVE this recurrence?

Comment: So, it is a nice question, though it may be difficult to answer.

Comment: What would the initial condition for this recurrence be? Based on the final answer it'd seem to be $P(x,2)=1$.

Comment: @Semiclassical You are correct. You can go through the link attached to read the original problem. The base case is $P(x, 2)  = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I explained how the two-dimensional recurrence can be solved directly without knowing the answer.

Let us first fix $x=1$. Then, we have the following recurrence:

$$P(1,n) = P(1,n-1)\left(\frac{n-2}{n-1}\right).$$

The [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%28n%29%3Df%28n-1%29%28n-2%29%2F%28n-1%29) of this is given by

$$P(1,n) = \frac{c}{n-1},$$

where from $P(1,2)=1$, we have $c=1$.

Then, for $x=2$, we have the following recurrence:

$$P(2,n) = \frac{1}{(n-2)(n-1)} + P(2,n-1)\left(\frac{n-3}{n-1}\right)$$

The [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%28n%29%3Df%28n-1%29%28n-3%29%2F%28n-1%29%2B1%2F%28%28n-1%29*%28n-2%29%29) of this is given by

$$P(2,n) = \frac{2c+n}{(n-1)(n-2)},$$

where from $P(2,3)=P(1,2) \times \frac{1}{2} +0=\frac{1}{2}$, we have $c=-1$.

Next, for $x=3$, we have the following recurrence:

$$P(3,n) = \frac{2}{(n-2)(n-1)} + P(3,n-1)\left(\frac{n-4}{n-1}\right)$$

The [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%28n%29%3Df%28n-1%29%28n-4%29%2F%28n-1%29%2B2%2F%28%28n-1%29*%28n-2%29%29) of this is given by

$$P(3,n) = \frac{6c+n^2-5n+6}{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)},$$

where from $P(3,4)=P(2,3) \times \frac{2}{3} +0=\frac{1}{3}$, we have $c=0$.

This can be continued in the same way.

---

As shown above, **our problem reduces** to solve the following one-dimensional recurrence:

$$f(n) = \frac{k-1}{(n-2)(n-1)} + f(n-1)\left(\frac{n-1-k}{n-1}\right)$$

for fixed $k$ and $n \ge k+1$  with $f(k+1)=\frac{1}{k}$ (set $n=k+1$ in the above).

Defining

$$g(n)=f(n)(n-1),$$

we obtain

$$\color{blue}{g(n)(n-2) = (k-1) + g(n-1)(n-1-k)}$$

with $\color{blue}{g(k+1)=1}$ for $\color{blue}{n \ge k+1}$.

From [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%28n%29%28n-2%29%3D%28k-1%29%2Bf%28n-1%29%28n-k-1%29), the general solution of the above is given by

$$g(n) = \frac{(c-1)\Gamma (n-k)}{\Gamma (2-k)\Gamma (n-1)}+1.$$

Now from $g(k+1)=1$, we obtain $c=1$, which gives  $g(n)=1$, and finally we obtain $$f(n)=\frac{1}{n-1}.$$

Thus, for any $k$ and $n\ge k+1$, we have

$$P(k,n) =f(n)=\frac{1}{n-1}.$$