# Probability of making $k$ shots, where the probability changes based on success

Tags: reference-request, conditional-probability, puzzle

I recall reading a puzzle that I believe was about shooting a basketball, where the probability of success for a given trial changes depending on previous successes. I searched around for it but had trouble finding it. I'm more interested in the name of the puzzle and some references than in the analysis of the problem itself.

It goes something like this:

> You're shooting free throws in basketball, and the probability of success depends on how many free throws you've made so far. In particular, on the $i$-th shot, you have a $\frac{1+s}{1+i}$ of making the basket, where $s$ is the number of previous successes.
>
> Given that you take $n$ shots, what is the probability of making exactly $k$ of them?

#### Example

- There is a $\frac12$ chance of making (or missing) the first shot.
- If you make the first shot, then there is a $\frac23$ chance of
  making the second shot.
- If you make the first two shots, then there is a $\frac34$ chance of
  making the third shot.
- However, if you make the first shot and miss the second shot, then
  there is a $\frac24$ chance of making the third.

Comment: This is known as Polya's urn. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1441545/, for example.

Comment: @MikeEarnest—if you want to put this as an answer, I'll accept it!